# How to render an SVG file in angular , I'm trying render the svg file by using <img> tag and <src> but its not displaying

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, svg, rendering

### HTML

```
            <img loading="lazy" src="{{filepath}}{{attach.attachmentList}}" 
                              (error)="imageurl($event)" alt=""
                class="attach_imge">
```

filepath and attachmentlist fetch from backend like this

https://kpostdrive.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ayyappan1072/katchup/baskar1992/27-01-2022/1642774653gas-container-red-color.svg

while I'm hitting the original URL i can download the file but i can't display it

Comment: Per https://fabianstiehle.com/mimetype/?check=https%3A%2F%2Fkpostdrive.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com%2Fayyappan1072%2Fkatchup%2Fbaskar1992%2F27-01-2022%2F1642774653gas-container-red-color.svg&hu= that has a mime-type of application/octet-stream it needs to be image/svg+xml so you need to fix that. This is not an angular or rendering problem.

Comment: how can I do that sir , can u please explain? whether  it needs to be done in aws server side or client side? also the same mime-type works fine for png file.

Comment: aws server side but you've no aws tags in your question so you've routed yourself to the wrong people.

Comment: i just added it , thanks for correcting me